# Samourai Wallet Can't Increase Transaction Fee with Error: "Cannot create CPFP transaction"

Tags: transaction-fees, samourai-wallet

Using the samourai wallet on android. I sent made a bitcoin transaction with a 1 sat/b fee. It's been uncofirmed for 2 days already. I tried to click on the "increase transaction fee" button, but I get hit with the error: *Cannot create CPFP transaction". How can I fix this issue?

And moving forward how should one pick an appropriate fee to choose instead of just guessing every time?

Comment: Did your original tx have a large enough change output? Child-pays-for-parent requires you to spend from the change

Comment: i'm not sure what that means... looks like my funds got returned back to me after 3 days....